# Table layout using std::cout

Tags: c++, formatting, stream, iostream

How do I format my output in C++ streams to print fixed width left-aligned tables? Something like

```
printf("%-14.3f%-14.3f\n", 12345.12345, 12345.12345);
```

poducing

```
12345.123     12345.123
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Include the standard header [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/query/search.cgi?q=iomanip) and go crazy. Specifically, the `setw` manipulator sets the output width. `setfill` sets the filling character.

Comment: Don't forget `std::left` for the left-alignment.

Comment: Is there a good reason why `printf()` wouldn't be a good choice?

Comment: @iharob The OP didn't ask for printf. That said, printf is a bad choice in C++ because it only handles builtin types, not user-defined types. It's also not type safe and allows potentially security relevant bugs to go undetected.

Answer (score 15):

```
std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed)
          << std::setprecision(3)
          << std::setw(18)
          << std::left
          << 12345.123;
```

Answer (score 11):

You may also consider more friendly functionality provided by one of these:

- [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/format/index.html) (powerful, but very heavy, more time and memory allocations than other mentioned)
- [Loki.SafeFormat](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.Printf)
- [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) (relatively new, but blazing fast library, also type-safe unlike the others)

Writing from memory, but should be something along these lines:

```
// Dumb streams:
printf("%-14.3f%-14.3f\n", 12345.12345, 12345.12345);

// For IOStreams you've got example in the other answers

// Boost Format supports various flavours of formatting, for example:
std::cout << boost::format("%-14.3f%-14.3f\n") % a % b;
std::cout << boost::format("%1$-14.3f%2$-14.3f\n") % a % b;
// To gain somewhat on the performance you can store the formatters:
const boost::format foo("%1$-14.3f%2$-14.3f\n");
std::cout << boost::format(foo) % a % b;

// For the Loki::Printf it's also similar:
Loki::Printf("%-14.3f%-14.3f\n")(a)(b);

// And finally FastFormat.Format (don't know the syntax for decimal places)
fastformat::fmtln(std::cout, "{0,14,,<}{1,14,,>}", a, b);
```

Also, if you plan to stick with any of these formatting libraries, examine thoroughly their limitations in context of expressibility, portability (and other library dependency), efficiency, support of internationalisation, type-safety, etc.

Comment: Links now, examples tomorrow afternoon (GMT time)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use stream manipulators:

http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060218/index.html